# Implement bootstrap in lit-element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit-element

I tried to implement bootstrap styling in my lit-element project. But I am struggling a little bit and don't know how to implement bootstrap into it. All my website navigation links are in the index.js i tried to add classes from bootstrap into my lit-element project and it doesnt work as i want and i couldn't find helping solutions on the internet. could you help me?

index.js

```
export const routes = [
    {
        route: "/",
        name: "home",
        pattern: "",
    },
    {
        route: "/example",
        name: "example",
        pattern: "example",
        element: html`<example-page />`,
    },
    {
        route: "/replacement_table",
        name: "replacement_table",
        pattern: "replacement_table",
        element: html`<replacement-table />`,
    },
    {
        route: "/replacement_form",
        name: "replacement_form",
        pattern: "replacement_form",
        element: html`<replacement-form .showMode=${false}/>`,
    },
    {
        route: "/login",
        name: "login",
        pattern: "login",
        element: html`<login-page />`
    },
    {
        route: "/suggestions_table",
        name: "suggestions-table",
        pattern: "suggestions_table",
        element: html`<suggestions-table />`,
    },
    {
        route: "/study",
        name: "study",
        pattern: "study",
        element: html`<new-study />`,
    },
    {
        route: "/approve_adjustment_form",
        name: "approve-adjustment-form",
        pattern: "approve_adjustment_form",
        element: html`<approve-adjustment-form />`,
    },
    {
        route: "/excel",
        name: "excel",
        pattern: "excel",
        element: html`<excel-info />`,
    }
    //PATTERN NEEDS TO BE THE SAME AS ROUTE!!!!!!
];
```

this is the styling that i want i copied this from bootstrap theme example.

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
```

this is my lit-element js code

```
    render() {
        return html`
            <div>
                <div>
                    <dev-tools />
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    ${routes.map(item => {
        return html`<app-link href="${item.route}">${item.name}</app-link>`;
    })}
                    <app-main active-route=${this.route}>
                        ${routes.map(item => {
        if (item.element) {
            return html`<div route="${item.name}">${item.element}</div>`;
        } else {
            return html`<h1 route="${item.name}">${item.name}</h1>`;
        }
    })}
                        <h1 route="not-found">ERROR404 PAGE NOT FOUND</h1>
                    </app-main>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to create a minimum example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render into the light-dom instead of the shadow-dom by setting the renderroot.

see: https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/

But beware: Rendering into children and not shadow DOM is generally not recommended. Your element will not have access to DOM or style scoping, and it will not be able to compose elements into its internal DOM.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="module">
import {
  LitElement,
  html,
  css
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";

class MyBadge extends LitElement {
  
 createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
 } 
  
 static get properties() {
    return {
      title: { type: String, reflect: true },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <h1>Example heading <span class="badge bg-secondary">${this.title}</span></h1>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-badge", MyBadge);
</script>
<my-badge title="SOME TEXT"></my-badge>
```