# Get raw string value by import with vite

Tags: css, import, web-component, vite, lit

I want to get raw string of css in npm module through vite.
According to vite manual,
https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string
It says we can get raw string by putting "?raw" at the end of identifier.

So I try this:

> import style from "swiper/css/bundle?raw";

But this shows error like:

> [vite] Internal server error: Missing "./css/bundle?raw" export in
> "swiper" package

If I use this:

> import style from "swiper/css/bundle";

There are no error, but css is not just load as string but handled as bundle css.
This is not good, because I want to use this css in my lit-based web components.
Are there any way to get css as raw string through vite?

Comment: Have you tried fetch?

Comment: In my case, fetch doesn't help, maybe, because I don't want to bind it in document root but want to bind it inside of web component's shadow root.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70767978/534858

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Evan You (Vite.js and Vue.js creator) [has added the `inline` toggle](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/2148#issuecomment-785161991) which fixes [the problem of styles also being added to the main CSS bundle when importing](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3246).

```
import style from "swiper/css/bundle.css?inline";
```

This toggle prevents your CSS from also being bundled into you main CSS bundle as a side effect of importing it into a string.